# How can I "deserialize" an HTML table data into a bi-dimensional array?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, junit, automated-tests

I need to perform **data validation** of two tables using **Selenium**.

Given a properly marked-up HTML table filled with data:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I want to "deserialize" this table (gather its data) into a bi-dimensional array (`String[][]`) using Selenium. The reason I want to do so is that I have another HTML table (on the other web-page) that contains supposedly the same data stored in it - and I need to perform **data validation** between those two tables.

I have tried lots of options on how to solve this problem, and iterative cell-by-cell data gathering (locating cells either using the **getTable()** or **getText()** methods) is not one of them - since it takes enormous amounts of time to complete a big table on an overloaded web-page.

JavaScript injection (using the **getEval()** method) is not available in my case since the table resides in an **<iframe>** that has an origin (base URL) that differs from the one of the main page. And according to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) this cannot be performed.

Guys, any idea on how to solve the given problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JAXB to deserialize the HTML text into plain java object hierarchy and then construct a 2D array from those objects.

Another option: parse the text as XML into a org.w3c.dom.Document and use [XPath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/) in Java to find and iterate over the elements.

Comment: Are you implying to use the **`getHtmlSource`** method? Are there any Selenium alternatives to get just a part of HTML instead of the whole?

Comment: Either using getHtmlSource/getBodySource and then finding the element or element.getAttribute("innerHTML")

Comment: Isn't **`innerHTML`** an object property other than an attribute?

Comment: It tries to get the attribute first, if that does not exist it looks for a property